# Infragisitics error

Tags: infragistics, ultrawingrid

How do I get rid of this build error in my winforms app?

> Error  121 The type 'Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridRow' exists in both 'c:\Program Files\Infragistics\NetAdvantage for .NET 2007 Volume 1 CLR 1.x\Windows Forms\Bin\Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.v7.1.dll' and 'c:\WINNT\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Infragistics2.Win.UltraWinGrid.v8.1\8.1.20081.1000__7dd5c3163f2cd0cb\Infragistics2.Win.UltraWinGrid.v8.1.dll'

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first guess i would say that you've referenced both `Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.v7.1.dll` and `Infragistics2.Win.UltraWinGrid.v8.1.dll`. CHeck your project's references. Also if Infragistics offer an *upgrade your project* type functionality when you install a new version, make sure it hasn't left stray references or `using` statements, or incorrect variable declarations that reference older versions of the componentry.

Answer (score 0):

also, there is 10.3 out there now. best to upgrade to latest version. Also Infragistics has "Version Utility" which allows you to upgrade your solution and projects to newer binaries easily (will update project references for you). but yeah as Slugster mentioned, you have 2 diffirent versions of infragistics dll in your solution and there is class name clashes.